# dictionary with lists - select the best(s) based on key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with lists, heading in the first row like this:

```
book = [{'A':1,'B':2,'C':3},{'A':4,'B':5,'C':6},{'A':5,'B':5,'C':7}]
```

Which is the best method to select lists based on the key (for instance 'B') and print the highest list(s), in this case:

```
[{'A':4,

  'B':5,

  'C':6}

 {'A':5,

  'B':5,

  'C':7}]
```

I tried this but no success

```
besties=[book[0]]
col='B'

for i in range(len(book)):
    for j in range(len(book)-i-1):
        if i[j][col]>besties[i][col]:
            besties.append(book[i])
    print(besties)
```

Comment: what do you mean highest list?

Comment: sorry for my English, I meant those lines with keys where column B contains the largest numbers.

Comment: Are you wanting only the dicts with the maximum value of B? Or an ordered list of the dicts sorted by the value of B?

Comment: dicts with the maximum value of B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 3 approaches:

1. Find the maximum value on that key, then find every element with that max key
2. Sort the array base on that key and get the latest elements with the same value
3. Add every element to the `result` array and empty it if a bigger value for that key was found.

Which depends on what you want to do with the information after that, or if you need to customize it later, or how large the data is going to be.

For example, the easiest to implement one is the first one.

```
def get_all_max_values_on(key_name):
    result = []
    # Change max_value to the first element if you have negative values as well
    max_value = -1
    for el in book:
        if el[key_name] > max_value:
            max_value = el[key_name]

    for el in book:
        if el[key_name] == max_value:
           result.append(el)

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first occurence by just doing

```
best = max(book, key=lambda x: x['B'])
```

Unfortunately, max doesn't return all occurences, so you have to loop through the dict a second time

```
best_B = best['B']
all_best = [book for book in books if book['B']==best_B]
```